# Loading multiple moustache.js/icanhas.js external templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, template-engine

I am currently building a javascript based website that uses [icanhaz.js](http://icanhazjs.com/) (fork of moustache.js) as a templating engine. The problem that I am having is that I want to load in 5 different template files, is there a way that I can make this more efficient.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get( "/path/to/template1.mst", function( template ) {
    ich.addTemplate("template1", template); //This is how templates are loaded in icanhas.js (similar to moustache)
  });

  $.get( "/path/to/template2.mst", function( template ) {
    ich.addTemplate("template2", template);
  });

  $.get( "/path/to/template3.mst", function( template ) {
    ich.addTemplate("template3", template);
  });

  $.get( "/path/to/template4.mst", function( template ) {
    ich.addTemplate("template4", template);
  });

  $.get( "/path/to/template5.mst", function( template ) {
    ich.addTemplate("template5", template);
  });

  renderScript()
});
```

Comment: I'm playing with the template engine these days, found different many Q&As hence I wonder if you could produce a way to achieve this? I think writing another template for loading templates is not possible?.. (: